# Implementing Curriculum Dropout in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

Is there anyone who can help me implement Curriculum Dropout by Pytorch. Thanks in advance, and any kind of help will be appreciable.

I want to do some experiments of Curriculum Dropout in Pytorch. Curriculum Dropout tries to use a time scheduling for adjusting the dropout rate in the neural networks. The related paper can be downloaded from [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06229).
The source code in python can be found [here](https://github.com/pmorerio/curriculum-dropout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a quick look at the paper and it seems like the main idea is to use a scheduled dropout rate instead of a fixed dropout rate.

Torch already has a Dropout module: `torch.nn.modules.dropout.Dropout`.

For your custom neural net using a Dropout module `dropout`, you can schedule the dropout rate simply by modifying `dropout.p` between optimization steps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am really a newbie to pytorch and starting to enjoy it. And I need to do these experiments within a short time before the deadline of a conference. Would you please help me write a custom module of dropout if it does not take you much time.  :)

Comment: @zongjie the point of this answer is exactly that: you do **not** need to write a custom module, you only need your training code to adjust `dropout.p` rate as a function of the training progress.

Comment: If I remember right, this paper doesn't actually use dropout in the traditional sense, it adds some kind of noise to activations with an increasing probability over the training period.